# I want to send list of objects from javascript to controller method via post

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to send list of objects to controller method but collection comes null in controller. And I am getting 500 Internal Server Error. I checked xhr network and my request payload is: {,…}

> collection: [{categoryID: 1, pageID: 1, positionX: 1, positionY: 1,
>   dimensionX: 3, dimensionY: 3},…] 0: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 1,
>   positionX: 1, positionY: 1, dimensionX: 3, dimensionY: 3} 1:
>   {categoryID: 1, pageID: 3, positionX: 1, positionY: 3, dimensionX: 3,
>   dimensionY: 7} 2: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 5, positionX: 1, positionY:
>   7, dimensionX: 2, dimensionY: 9} 3: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 6,
>   positionX: 2, positionY: 7, dimensionX: 3, dimensionY: 9} 4:
>   {categoryID: 1, pageID: 7, positionX: 3, positionY: 1, dimensionX: 5,
>   dimensionY: 3} 5: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 8, positionX: 3, positionY:
>   3, dimensionX: 5, dimensionY: 5} 6: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 9,
>   positionX: 3, positionY: 5, dimensionX: 5, dimensionY: 7} 7:
>   {categoryID: 1, pageID: 10, positionX: 3, positionY: 7, dimensionX: 4,
>   dimensionY: 9} 8: {categoryID: 1, pageID: 11, positionX: 4, positionY:
>   7, dimensionX: 5, dimensionY: 9}

grid.html

```
<button type="button" class="button" style="margin-left:400px" onclick="saveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
```

grid.js

```
function saveChanges() {
    var collection = [];
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.grid-container>.icon')).forEach((element) => {
        var single = {};
        single['categoryID'] = 1;
        single['pageID'] = parseInt(element.getAttribute("icon-id"));
        var gridArea=element.style.gridArea.split(" / ");
        single['positionX']=parseInt(gridArea[0]);
        single['positionY'] = parseInt(gridArea[1]);
        single['dimensionX'] = parseInt(gridArea[2]);
        single['dimensionY'] = parseInt(gridArea[3]);
        collection.push(single);
    });
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST",  "PageView/Create", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({'collection': collection }));
}
```

PageViewController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(List<PageCategoryPageViewModel> collection)
        {
            try
            {
                collection.ForEach((x)=>_pageCategoryPageService.CreatePageCategoryPage(x));
                return View("Grid");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View("Grid");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to edit a grid and save it? If so, could you show us this 'grid'?

Comment: What does the model `PageCategoryPageViewModel` look like?